# How can i quickly go to bottom of YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

i want to go to bottom of this page [https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie/videos] and watch videos from there to top, and since there's a lot video, if i scroll to bottom, it would take a lot of unnecessary memory (i mean my scrolling become buggy and jams sometimes, since my pc is old); so is there any JavaScript to insert in page and go directly to the bottom? or any other way you suggest, tnx.

Comment: If you drag the scroll bar to the bottom, you get to the bottom of the page in about 1 second.  That seems pretty direct using the built-in features.  Why do you think that uses more memory than some other way?

Comment: Which OS are you talking about?  Which Browser? In Windows you could just hit CTRL+End.

Comment: @fixer1234: yeah, but it keeps auto-loading more and more

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: chrome last version, windows 7 32bit

Comment: So you want to suppress page rendering until you reach the bottom so that stuff farther up the page isn't cached?

Comment: @fixer1234: yeah, I don't want stuff farther up the page cached, sorry for the late replay

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  How is Ctrl+End different from pressing just the End button?

Comment: You cannot change autoload feature. Instead use a different sorting method.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to view YouTube videos from oldest to newest is to actually sort the videos from oldest to newest in the drop-down menu at the upper-right corner of where your videos are appearing.

Comment: how to sort that way? what if i need middle and there is still lot to scroll?